# Typescript: DOM - type null is not assignable to type HTMLFormElement

Tags: typescript, dom

When using query selector to get a form element from my html page as follows:

```js
let form: HTMLFormElement = document.querySelector('.credential_form');
```

The compiler gives me the following error:
`Type HTMLFormElement | null is not assignable to type HTMLFormElement. Type null is not assignable to type HTMLFormElement`

Is there a way that i can get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error has occurred because the compiler is unable to determine whether it will find a form element with class 'credential_form' in your html. If it does not, querySelector returns null. Therefore it gives form a union type HTMLFormElement | null to cover both scenarios.

Easiest way to get around this is to use the ! operator (null assertion)
This tells the compiler that you are sure that form will not have a null type

let form: HTMLFormElement = document.querySelector('.credential_form')!;

This should do it!

Answer (score 0):

The default return type of the [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method is a nullable `Element`.

You can use a custom [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) to ensure that the `querySelector` method returned the expected element:

```ts
function assertElement<TagName extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(
  tagName: TagName,
  element: Element | null | undefined,
): asserts element is HTMLElementTagNameMap[TagName] {
  if (element == null) {
    throw new TypeError(`Expected <${tagName}> but found ${element}`);
  } else if (element.tagName !== tagName.toUpperCase()) {
    throw new TypeError(`Expected <${tagName}> but found <${element.tagName}>`);
  }
}
```

Then, use it on the value returned by the `querySelector` method to assert that the element is of the expected type:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=79#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoFEA2GAthmFADwAqyA5gHLImIYAeUpAJqogNYYCecYIgASlALIAZAsVJRq9RhnHIADgD4AFAChEiKLQYkAXIgVGMAGl3NCJMqZn2oiAD6IwIfPjeJwHDGAYMAwOawBKUzRMHG4MOzlEGG4xKSc5cyUVVQBtTJIAXUQAbxsYYU142TJEAF5ajy98cJKbPSgACyw4AHcPDD7KflUMXCxurE0AA1wWEehQxHIAEmKDRRIAX3VEACMQF2A4f0RVqudNqfCAbhtN20wkivO5ADp1i0QAQnr9QyV3nAAKqqEZYADCaAwmnCLVKenaXV6-UGw1G4zgkxmcwwCw4S1WHyU2z2B0QRxOK2KLzI73+W3UV1uek22lZ2kIh0xRDqiA4cAgIGcrwAjiBsPwAMpVaCYzQAcleECwoTkMGQ+AA+kcsER5TcbAB6Q0APQA-NptMbEABJYSdDC2aoufkYVBgeUuVjJFyYpLuz0ocncp3OazW5BmNFjCaIHowbx7R2dbo9JAdbCO5AuLDgWAmbTRbB4BJkTQAIh1RHLlmDuoNVsNiAA8g6sPHMLXkMB2O3kFh8Q7EBA4ERVAnsHGEz4eGBkZ1s4hK9zy-7RBJJAAxbnpBzaEdgVBwQivfBwGiaKsGhE3hHG83aIA)

```ts
let form = document.querySelector('.credential_form');
  //^? let form: Element | null

// If the element doesn't exist or isn't a form element,
// a TypeError will be thrown here at runtime:
assertElement("form", form);

// Otherwise, afterward the compiler will know that "form" is HTMLFormElement:
console.log(form);
          //^? let form: HTMLFormElement
```